# Best approach to storing ArrayLists in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm new to Android programming however I do have some Java experience.

What I would like to know is, what is the best approach for storing ArrayLists and such in SQLite for Android? Storing in tables takes, in my opinion, the point of OO-Programming however I don't wanna use db4o since later I wanna port my application to iPhone.

When it comes to this, which approach do you guys use? A fairly simple example, if I have a class "House" with an ArrayList of "Objects" how should I store them. Also I don't wanna use Serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic example on using a sqlite database to store data. basically every object will represent a single row in your table (every primitive will be a column). you will query the table and use a cursor object to traverse through the elements. its somewhat the database alternative to an arraylist.

Comment: And how should I store the information of which objects does the house contain?

Comment: have you ever worked with sql? i need to know the level of details. if you want to experiment with database download SQLite Spy for example and you can create your own sample database and try out a structure, operations etc..

Comment: For how to make an sqlite database look at the Notepad Tutorial and the Notepad Sample code provided in your Android sdk directory (the samples) and http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html. The thing i recomend on android is building a content Provider which is explained in that tutorial and can be seen in the samples. there are 3 classes of importance. the DB class where you define the tables, the ContentProvider class where you define the access and create the tables (upgrade the database etc via a sqlite helper) and third the manifest registration of the provider

Comment: And you will be able to reuse the table SQL syntax for iphone also i believe. The structure will be the same, the language of accessing and manipulating with data will be different.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your ArrayList in the form of a Blob. Here is how you convert an ArrayList into a Blob.

```
try {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);

    // mArrayList is the ArrayList you want to store
    oos.writeObject(mArrayList);
    byte[] buff = bos.toByteArray();

    // You can store the blob in the database
    Blob blob = new SerialBlob(buff);
} catch (Exception e){
}
```

Now, this only works if you ArrayList is Serializable. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't wanna use blobs since I wanna port the database to iOS aswell.

Comment: In that case, I think the best way is to create another table which takes all the data in your ArrayList and reference them from your main table.